# Rebinding CTRL-ALT-[C|V] to CTRL-SHIFT-[C|V] in URxvt >= 9.20

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, clipboard, rxvt

Since `URxvt` 9.20, text can be copied to the clipboard with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (and also pasted from with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>).

But, I already use these bindings for another thing.

So how can I rebind, in `URxvt` >=9.20 it to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> for paste) ?

Comment: related question on SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43305190/how-to-change-the-default-shortcuts-for-copy-paste-in-urxvt

Answer (score 33):

The eval extension shipped with rxvt-unicode has paste_clipboard and selection_to_clipboard actions for this, that can be bound to any keysym (see [here](https://github.com/muennich/urxvt-perls/issues/78#event-889376223)).

In your `.Xresources` add:

```
URxvt.keysym.Shift-Control-V: eval:paste_clipboard
URxvt.keysym.Shift-Control-C: eval:selection_to_clipboard
```

To disable the previous keybindings, you'll also need:

```
URxvt.keysym.Control-Meta-c: builtin-string:
URxvt.keysym.Control-Meta-v: builtin-string:
```

You can reload the file with:

```
xrdb -load .Xresources
```

You'll need to restart rxvt for the changes to take effect.

Comment: this didn't work at all until I also added or edited  this to `.Xresources:  URxvt.perl-ext-common: default`  #also disable keycaps as per  this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/444777/8827

Comment: I had to do the same as @marinara. In my case, I am already using the `font-size` perl extension (allows for Ctrl+= and Ctrl+- to zoom in/out), so I had to list the two extensions as a comma-separated list, like so: `URxvt.perl-ext-common: default,font-size` . I'm using urxvt v9.22 on Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 3):

All of the existing answers handle the second half of the question (how to add keybindings for clipboard operations to new keys), but don't answer the first half (how to *free up* the original keybindings).

The answer is to simply bind them to `builtin-string:` (if you wish them to be sent verbatim; otherwise, to the desired action). I.e., in `.Xresources`:

```
URxvt.keysym.C-M-c: builtin-string:
```

Or, on the command line:

```
-keysym.C-M-c builtin-string:
```

Answer (score 2):

The code implements these two bindings like this:

```
  if (ctrl && meta && (keysym == XK_c || keysym == XK_v))
    { 
      if (keysym == XK_v)
        selection_request (ev.time, Sel_Clipboard);
      else if (selection.len > 0)
        { 
          free (selection.clip_text);
          selection.clip_text = rxvt_wcsdup (selection.text, selection.len);
          selection.clip_len = selection.len;
          selection_grab (CurrentTime, true);
        }

      return;
    }
```

You cannot use the `keysym` resource to rebind something else, since *that* only maps to strings (no modifiers such as <kbd>control</kbd> and <kbd>alt</kbd>).

However, you could use the Perl extension, which has methods for working with selections.  But you'd have to write a Perl script to tie those together.

Answer (score 1):

To use the eval extensions (`paste_clipboard` and `selection_to_clipboard`) [mentioned in @Enno's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/329556) you can add the following to your `.Xresources` file:

```
URxvt.keysym.Shift-Control-V: eval:paste_clipboard
URxvt.keysym.Shift-Control-C: eval:selection_to_clipboard
```

Comment: By itself, this doesn’t really answer the question.  You can improve it by describing how to use the `.Xresources` file to bind the keys, since [Enno’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/294337/80216#329556) doesn’t.