# How to disable the Ctrl+Shift binding (ISO 14755) in urxvt?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, rxvt

Whenever the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> key combo is pressed, the text `ISO 14755 mode` text pops up at the corner of the terminal window in urxvt. Is there a way to remove this without having to rebuild urxvt?

I'm using a pre-built version of urxvt in Manjaro Linux (i3wm). I wanted to have the copy and paste binded to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> respectively. I followed [this solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/329556/152132) and worked. But that's when this problem started occurring.

According to [this source](https://www.reddit.com/r/urxvt/comments/35x03n/if_youve_been_vexed_by_urxvts_picture_insert_mode/), the switch can be solved by adding these two lines to the `~/.Xresources` file.

```
URxvt.iso14755: true
URxvt.iso14755_52: false
```

However, the mini-dialog still pops with `ISO 14755 mode` each time I execute copy or paste. Another solution involves removing the iso support before building the package using the `./configure --disable-iso14755`, but I would like to solve it without having to reinstall the package.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You've disabled keycap picture insert mode but not basic ISO 14755 mode. To disable both, set both to false.

```
URxvt.iso14755: false
URxvt.iso14755_52: false
```

After changing `~/.Xresources`, reload the file with

```
xrdb -merge <~/.Xresources
```

Comment: Thank you so much for solving it! I surfed all over the place before deciding to make the post. Could you please explain what the last line does? I just did `xrdb ~/.Xresources` then reloaded the terminal to fix it. What does the `-merge` flag and the redirection do in this context?

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac Without `-merge`, this removes any other X resources that you have. That's all right if you're loading from a file and you always put all your resources in that file, but not if you split them over multiple files or if you add some dynamically or if you're loading more resources during a session.