# How to Use Control+V Keys to Paste in urxvt Terminal?

Tags: terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, clipboard, rxvt

I see many questions about keybinds in urxvt, but I don't see this exact one. I'd like to use `control+v` in order to paste into the terminal. (without the shift. or alt/meta key. etc.)

My goal is to be able to paste from other applications like a text editor or Chrome. (noting this in case it's relevant to the "type" of paste-function/clipboard involved, as I understand there may be more than one.) I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 with i3 window manager.

Here's what I've tried, modified from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/329556/56490), but it didn't work.

I added the following in `~/.Xresrouces`

```
! Do I need to remove/change any default bindings first?
URxvt.keysym.Control-Meta-v: builtin-string:

! use control+v for "paste"
URxvt.keysym.Control-V: eval:paste_clipboard

! I read these are needed to disable other behavior of control key
URxvt.iso14755: false 
URxvt.iso14755_52: false
```

After saving the file above, I entered the command to reload it:

```
xrdb -merge .Xresources
```

... but after restarting urxvt, even after rebooting, I still cannot paste using `control+v`.

What lines do I need to add to .Xresources file, or what do I need to do otherwise, in order to use control+v as the shortcut for "paste" in urxvt?

Comment: I'm not sure you can override `Ctrl + C` because it will simply break your terminal but `Ctrl + V` should be possible :-) But still I wouldn't go this way because it may mess with your muscle memory: you'll have to use `Ctrl + Alt + C` to copy and `Ctrl + V` to paste.

Comment: Sorry about the irrelevant reference to "C" here. I've removed it.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done using urxvt's scripting feature and `xdotool`.  urxvt can load Perl scripts which can trigger actions for key combos.  My urxvt configuration uses this feature to feed <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> into the terminal whenever <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> is pressed.

This is really only half of a solution though, as the way I've implemented it involves a hacky workaround (the `sleep 0.25`), in practice this has the desired effect and doesn't cause any problems except the small amount of lag, but in theory it's not guaranteed to work.

in `.Xresources`:

```
URxvt.keysym.Control-Shift-V: eval:paste_clipboard
URxvt.perl-ext-common: default,ctrl_v_paste
URxvt.iso14755: false
URxvt.iso14755_52: false
```

create `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/urxvt/perl/ctrl_v_paste`:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

=head1 NAME

paste - paste with ctrl v

=head1 DESCRIPTION

paste with ctrl v

=cut

sub on_init {
   my ($self) = @_;

   my $hotkey = "C-v";

   $self->bind_action ($hotkey, "%:start")
      or warn "unable to register '$hotkey' as hotkey\n";

   ()
}

sub on_action {
   my ($self, $action) = @_;
   
   $action eq "start"
      and $self->enter;

   ()
}

sub enter {
   my ($self) = @_;
   system("sleep 0.25 && xdotool getactivewindow key ctrl+shift+v &");
}
```

edit: since the time that I last answered I've found a better way to paste, replace `system("sleep 0.25 && xdotool getactivewindow key ctrl+shift+v &");` with:

```
my $clipboard = `xclip -o`;
$self->tt_paste($clipboard);
```